# Return stops loop iteraction

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function that returns all of the user friends, but is only returning one row instead of all the rows associated with the query.

```
 function getAllFriends($email){

             $myid = $this->getStudentId($email);

             $this->db->where('aluno_id',$myid);
             $sql =  $this->db->get('mutamba_amigos');

             if($sql->num_rows() > 0){

                 foreach ($sql->result() as $r){
                     $this->db->where('id',$r->amizade_id);

                     $sql2 =  $this->db->get('mutamba_amizades');

                     if($sql2->num_rows() > 0){

                            foreach ($sql2->result() as $f){
                                $this->db->where('id',$f->aluno_id);
                                $sql3 = $this->db->get('alunos');
                                if ($sql3->num_rows() > 0) {

                                   // echo "<br> Model rows: ". $sql3->num_rows();
                                    return $sql3->result();
                                }else{

                                      return false;
                                }
                             } 

                        }

                 }


             }else{
                // echo 'nothing found';
                return false;
             }


         }
```

If I comment the `return $sql3->result();' and  uncomment the`echo "
 Model rows: ". $sql3->num_rows();`the count is right.  I know it must be the`return` stopping the loop iteraction. How can I solve this?

Any help please, will be very greatful.

Comment: That's exactly the expected behavior of `return`. It [immediately returns control to the caller of the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php), mid-loop, or wherever. Do you want to return an array of results from `$sql3`?

Comment: yes @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: You are calling `result()` on $sql3 for each row returned by $sql2. Do you want those results from $sql3 concatenated into a single 2D array and returned, or as an array (3D) of rowsets, where each of the outer array is a set from $sql2?

Comment: no, i just want results from the last query

Answer (score 0):

Right, I created an array "friends" and instead of returning the result from `$sql3` I used `array_push($friends,$sql3->result())` then returned the  'friends' array, after the loop block. If there's a more straight forward way, please let me know. I've been a bit rusty in mysql and php so, would appreciate other solutions. Thanks.